# How can I integrate handlebars with backbone

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple single page application which is for my own learning. The page has a UL of all the services that I provide. This list comes from a JSON. Next to each service there is a price for it, and a check-box which the user can select if he needs the service.

Under the list there is a total price value for all the services selected. Based on this, can you please tell me what wrong am I doing? I am trying to integrate the list of services as a handlebar template.
Here is the HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Your first Backbone.js App | Tutorialzine </title>

    <!-- Google web fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

    <!-- The main CSS file -->
    <link href="http://localhost/backbone-demo/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    <form id="main" method="post" action="submit.php">
        <h1>My Services</h1>
        <div id="serviceTable"></div>
            <ul id="services">              
        <script id="services-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          <!-- The services will be inserted here via handlebars-->

          {{#each services}}
          <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="{{title}}"/> {{title}}
              <span>${{price}} </span>
          </li>
          {{/each}}

        </script>
            </ul>

        <p id="total">total: <span>$0</span></p>

        <input type="submit" id="order" value="Order" />

    </form>



    <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/backbone-demo/assets/js/libs/underscore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/backbone-demo/assets/js/libs/backbone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/backbone-demo/assets/js/libs/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/backbone-demo/assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(function(){

// Create a model for the services
var Service = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // Will contain three attributes.
    // These are their default values

    defaults:{
        title: 'My service',
        price: 100,
        checked: false
    },

    // Helper function for checking/unchecking a service
    toggle: function(){
        this.set('checked', !this.get('checked'));
    }
});


// Create a collection of services
var ServiceList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // Will hold objects of the Service model
    model: Service,

    // Return an array only with the checked services
    getChecked: function(){         
        return this.where({checked:true});
    }
});

//Retrieve the list of services
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "assets/services.json",
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
        // Prefill the collection with a number of services.            
        var services = new ServiceList(response);                   
        var ServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'li',

            events:{
                'click': 'toggleService'
            },

            initialize: function(){

                // Set up event listeners. The change backbone event
                // is raised when a property changes (like the checked field)                   
                this.listenTo(services, 'change', this.render);
            },

            render: function(){
                var tpl = Handlebars.compile($("#services-template").html());
                //console.log(this.$el.selector);
                this.$el.html(tpl({services: services.toJSON()}));
                //console.log(this.$el);
                $('#serviceTable').append(this.$el);

                //document.getElementById('serviceTable').innerHTML = serviceData;
                // Create the HTML                  
                /* this.$el.html('<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="' + this.model.get('title') + '" /> ' + this.model.get('title') + '<span>$' + this.model.get('price') + '</span>');
                this.$('input').prop('checked', this.model.get('checked')); */

                // Returning the object is a good practice
                // that makes chaining possible
                return this;
            },

            toggleService: function(){
                this.model.toggle();
            }
        });

        // The main view of the application
        var App = Backbone.View.extend({

            // Base the view on an existing element
            el: $('#main'),

            initialize: function(){

                // Cache these selectors
                this.total = $('#total span');
                this.list = $('#services');

                // Listen for the change event on the collection.
                // This is equivalent to listening on every one of the 
                // service objects in the collection.
                this.listenTo(services, 'change', this.render);


                // Create views for every one of the services in the
                // collection and add them to the page

                services.each(function(service){

                    var view = new ServiceView({ model: service });
                    this.list.append(view.render().el);

                }, this);   // "this" is the context in the callback
            },

            render: function(){

                // Calculate the total order amount by agregating
                // the prices of only the checked elements

                var total = 0;
                console.log(services.getChecked());

                Handlebars.each(services.getChecked(), function(elem){
                    console.log(total);
                    total += elem.get('price');
                });

                // Update the total price
                this.total.text('$'+total);

                return this;

            }

        });

        new App();

    }
});
```

});

Comment: And what is wrong?

Comment: The list is getting repeated 4 times. The total is not being added.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a workable snippet of your code. You have defined a `ServiceView`, which is created for each service in your set, however within this view, you are working with the collection as a whole, not `this.model` and your handlebars template has a for loop in it.

This means that you end up displaying the collection as many times as there are models in the collection. The example below duplicates the list twice as there are 2 records in the list.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- Rename your `ServiceView` to `ServicesView` and remove the loop within App initialize.
- Remove the loop in your template and change the call to `this.$el.html(tpl(this.model.toJSON()));`

```js
// Create a model for the services
var Service = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // Will contain three attributes.
    // These are their default values

    defaults:{
        title: 'My service',
        price: 100,
        checked: false
    },

    // Helper function for checking/unchecking a service
    toggle: function(){
        this.set('checked', !this.get('checked'));
    }
});


// Create a collection of services
var ServiceList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // Will hold objects of the Service model
    model: Service,

    // Return an array only with the checked services
    getChecked: function(){         
        return this.where({checked:true});
    }
});

//Retrieve the list of services
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.mocky.io/v2/588b429d300000d11afa8d97",
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
        // Prefill the collection with a number of services.
        var services = new ServiceList(response);                   
        var ServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'li',

            events:{
                'click': 'toggleService'
            },

            initialize: function(){

                // Set up event listeners. The change backbone event
                // is raised when a property changes (like the checked field)                   
                this.listenTo(services, 'change', this.render);
            },

            render: function(){
                var tpl = Handlebars.compile($("#services-template").html());
                //console.log(this.$el.selector);
                this.$el.html(tpl({services: services.toJSON()}));
                //console.log(this.$el);
                $('#serviceTable').append(this.$el);

                //document.getElementById('serviceTable').innerHTML = serviceData;
                // Create the HTML                  
                /* this.$el.html('<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="' + this.model.get('title') + '" /> ' + this.model.get('title') + '<span>$' + this.model.get('price') + '</span>');
                this.$('input').prop('checked', this.model.get('checked')); */

                // Returning the object is a good practice
                // that makes chaining possible
                return this;
            },

            toggleService: function(){
                this.model.toggle();
            }
        });

        // The main view of the application
        var App = Backbone.View.extend({

            // Base the view on an existing element
            el: $('#main'),

            initialize: function(){

                // Cache these selectors
                this.total = $('#total span');
                this.list = $('#services');

                // Listen for the change event on the collection.
                // This is equivalent to listening on every one of the 
                // service objects in the collection.
                this.listenTo(services, 'change', this.render);


                // Create views for every one of the services in the
                // collection and add them to the page

                services.each(function(service){

                    var view = new ServiceView({ model: service });
                    this.list.append(view.render().el);

                }, this);   // "this" is the context in the callback
            },

            render: function(){

                // Calculate the total order amount by agregating
                // the prices of only the checked elements

                var total = 0;
                console.log(services.getChecked());

                Handlebars.each(services.getChecked(), function(elem){
                    console.log(total);
                    total += elem.get('price');
                });

                // Update the total price
                this.total.text('$'+total);

                return this;

            }

        });

        new App();
      }
  });
```

```html
<form id="main" method="post" action="submit.php">
        <h1>My Services</h1>
        <div id="serviceTable"></div>
            <ul id="services">              
        <script id="services-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          <!-- The services will be inserted here via handlebars-->

          {{#each services}}
          <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="{{title}}"/> {{title}}
              <span>${{price}} </span>
          </li>
          {{/each}}

        </script>
            </ul>

        <p id="total">total: <span>$0</span></p>

        <input type="submit" id="order" value="Order" />

    </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```